# JS - Copy colour value to another elements

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to copy the color value from the `<h1>` element to `<path>` elements.

```
<div id='my_id'>
<h1 style='color:orange'>What What</h1>
<div id='my_element'>

<svg>

<path d="M10 10"></path>
<path d="M10 10"></path>
<path d="M10 10"></path>

</svg>

</div>
</div>
```

```
mycolor_element = document.querySelectorAll('#my_id h1')[0]; 
let my_value = window.getComputedStyle(mycolor_element).color;
document.querySelectorAll('#my_element svg path')[0].style.fill = my_value;
```

I expect that if my `<h1>` is orange then my `<path>`s are also orange.

Comment: Can you provide example HTML?

Comment: And any error messages you might have in your console

Comment: It could also help to show us the code with getElementById that works...

Comment: if you added your html it would be obvious why your selectors aren't working. Because actually the code would work if you had the corresponding elements

Comment: You need `querySelector`, **not** `querySelectorAll`, and it's **impossible** it does not work if your element exists and you typed the `id` correctly

Comment: everyone blaming for querySelector vs querySelectorAll but did you read the question??

Comment: Try: `mycolor_element = my_id.querySelector('h1')`

Comment: @w2019s if you wanted to change the style of many paths you should have edited your question instead of asking on comments and you should check on mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll how to select multiple elements with a single selector and how to loop over them

Comment: @DiegoD I did it. Can please someone help now?

Comment: @w2019 if you checked the link I suggested before you will find how to perform a `forEach` over the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll`. If scrolling the page required too much effort, this is the exact spot https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll#accessing_the_matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` (if is just one element) with `window.getComputedStyle` for catch color of element then set it to the svg like:

```js
const mycolor_element = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#my_id > h1')).color;

document.querySelectorAll('#my_element > svg > path').forEach(el => el.style.fill = mycolor_element);
```

```css
h1 {
  color: orange
}
```

```html
<div id='my_id'>
  <h1 style='color:orange'>What What</h1>
  <div id='my_element'>
    <svg>

     <path fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="1" d=" m 44 0 c 0 0 0 10 0 10 c 0 0 -88 0 -88 0 c 0 0 0 -10 0 -10 c 0 0 88 0 88 0 z" />
     <path fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="1" d=" m 44 15 c 0 0 0 10 0 10 c 0 0 -88 0 -88 0 c 0 0 0 -10 0 -10 c 0 0 88 0 88 0 z" />
     <path fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="1" d=" m 44 30 c 0 0 0 10 0 10 c 0 0 -88 0 -88 0 c 0 0 0 -10 0 -10 c 0 0 88 0 88 0 z" />

    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the code worked as is with no modification as long as the html is there .. querySelectorAll()[0] was just a wrong practice but it's not the core issue

Comment: That's only an example for help OP to solve his problem.

Comment: I now understand the importance of providing details when asking questions ^^ What can I do if I want to copy this color for many paths?

Comment: What path contains?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini This:

<path fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="1" d=" M44.11800003051758,-5.190000057220459 C44.11800003051758,-5.190000057220459 44.11800003051758,5.190000057220459 44.11800003051758,5.190000057220459 C44.11800003051758,5.190000057220459 -44.11800003051758,5.190000057220459 -44.11800003051758,5.190000057220459 C-44.11800003051758,5.190000057220459 -44.11800003051758,-5.190000057220459 -44.11800003051758,-5.190000057220459 C-44.11800003051758,-5.190000057220459 44.11800003051758,-5.190000057220459 44.11800003051758,-5.190000057220459z"></path>

Comment: thanks but it still work just for the first path element =(

Comment: As you can see from my example all work, your html is different for sure :)

Comment: No :D I copied the same HTML and duplicated the path element, but they were in the same position, so I couldn't see the other paths. But you are right it works thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this task by applying a `fill:currentColor` property value to your `<path>` elements:

```
path{
  fill:currentColor;
}
```

This way all paths can inherit the fill color from the parent element's (text) `color` property:

```js
let h1 = document.querySelector('#my_id h1'); 
let h1Color = window.getComputedStyle(h1).color;
let svgWrap = document.getElementById('svgWrap');

svgWrap.style.color = h1Color;
```

```css
.colorOrange{
  color:orange
}

.svgCurrentColor path{
  fill:currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div class='colorOrange'>
  <h1>Inherit color via css</h1>
  <div class='svgWrap'>
    <svg class="svgCurrentColor">
      <path fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="1" d=" m 44 0 c 0 0 0 10 0 10 c 0 0 -88 0 -88 0 c 0 0 0 -10 0 -10 c 0 0 88 0 88 0 z" />
      <path fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="1" d=" m 44 15 c 0 0 0 10 0 10 c 0 0 -88 0 -88 0 c 0 0 0 -10 0 -10 c 0 0 88 0 88 0 z" />
      <path fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="1" d=" m 44 30 c 0 0 0 10 0 10 c 0 0 -88 0 -88 0 c 0 0 0 -10 0 -10 c 0 0 88 0 88 0 z" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>


<div id='my_id'>
  <h1 style="color:purple">Inherit color via js</h1>
  <div id='svgWrap' >
    <svg class="svgCurrentColor">
      <path fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="1" d=" m 44 0 c 0 0 0 10 0 10 c 0 0 -88 0 -88 0 c 0 0 0 -10 0 -10 c 0 0 88 0 88 0 z" />
      <path fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="1" d=" m 44 15 c 0 0 0 10 0 10 c 0 0 -88 0 -88 0 c 0 0 0 -10 0 -10 c 0 0 88 0 88 0 z" />
      <path fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="1" d=" m 44 30 c 0 0 0 10 0 10 c 0 0 -88 0 -88 0 c 0 0 0 -10 0 -10 c 0 0 88 0 88 0 z" />
    </svg>

  </div>
</div>
```

So you might not need any javaScript at all.

Comment: The CSS solution worked for me (thanks for letting me know that "currentColor" exists :) but I'll wait for a js "forEach" solution as well.

Answer (score -4):

```
 document.querySelectorAll
```

This method is not used to select one element only.
Use the

```
document.querySelector
```

method instead.

Comment: This is a better practise but doesn't answer the question

Comment: If element has id u dont have to querySelect it first directly use elementid as a variable